# How to get data from ListView. (My List View has 3 items)

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I want retrieve the data from the Listview, where my list is having 4 items like, name, date, sem, category.

i want to read the text present in the list view and pass it to another activity.

Comment: What you tried?post it

Comment: Is your data in ListView are JsonData or Static data? Show your code.

Comment: ListView gets its data from an adapter.  To get to the data, its helpful to know what type of adapter you used.  As well as the code for the getView method of the adapter, to know what type of Views the ListView is displaying.  Finally, please clarify if you want "all data" passed to the new activity, or just the data you clicked on.

Comment: my ListView is having 4 textview elements, onItemClickListener() must have to give the data in each textview

Comment: @Piyush it's an Json data read from the webpage.

Comment: @PunithK i can only help once you post your adapter type, o/w i'm making significant assumptions.  I'm pretty sure that's true for any answer you receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are retrieving your data from server then you need to get item on item click of ListView. Like

```
  listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

              String name =urarraylist.get(position).get("name");// here you have to pas keyname which is put inyour Hashmap arraylist
              String category =urarraylist.get(position).get("category");
              String date=urarraylist.get(position).get("date");
              String sem=urarraylist.get(position).get("sem");
              Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),anotheractivity.class);
              i.putExtra("name", name);
              i.putExtra("category ", category );
              i.putExtra("date", date);
              i.putExtra("sem", sem);
              startActivity(i); 
            }
        });
```

Now retrieve this data in your next Activity on onCreate() method. Like

```
       Intent n = getIntent();
       String name = n.getStringExtra("name");
       String category = n.getStringExtra("category ");
       String date= n.getStringExtra("date");
       String sem= n.getStringExtra("sem");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude.. I tried the one u have given. Just i tried it. it's working. Love your support..

Answer (score 1):

As it's name suggest, a `ListView` doesn't contains data, it only contains `Views`. These views are often created from an array or a `List` via an `Adapter`. So you have to ask your adapter to retrieve the data.

Unfortunately there is no default method for that, so you'll have to create your own getter, or you can also loop on the `getItem()` method associated with the `getCount()` one on your ListView's adapter.

Comment: He can retrieve the ID and query the DB or faster would be to iterate the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                 String name=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                  Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),anotheractivity.class);
                  i.putExtra("USERNAME", name);
                  startActivity(i); 
                }
            });
```

if you click the listview row the value from corresponding position will be fetched and passed to intent and further to  next activity.

The magic lies here:

```
 String name=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Comment: if you click the listview get the value from corresponding position and intent the value into nextactivity

Comment: down voters please leave the comment,what mistake i did here?

Comment: list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
Intent i = new Intent(DeptEvents.this, ShowDeptEvent.class);
i.putExtra("sem", sem.toString());
i.putExtra("date",date.toString());
i.putExtra("desc", desc.toString());
i.putExtra("name", name.toString());
i.putExtra("dept", dept.toString());
startActivity(i);
} });

Comment: In the above code i want to pass the each position textview to next activity.

Comment: Removed the Downvote after editing the question and explaining what your code does.

Comment: @PunithK its not possible to move full listview into the another activity at a single click

Comment: @Boopathi on clicking listview, can i get at least, the each textview present in the listview.

Comment: The default implementation on a baseAdapter is to return NULL on getItem.  Idk if this will work on an ArrayAdapter, but OP never stated his adapter type.